# Finite element mesh not resolving features

Tags: mesh, finite-element-method

I am trying to make a finite element mesh in 2D. The features are not found by `ToElementMesh`. This is a shelf bracket with nails. I build the region using `RegionDifference` and `RegionUnion` and the result is clear.

```
   Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
L = 0.2; (* Bracket side length *)
d = 0.02;  (* End edge lenght *)
r = L - d;   (* radius of curved edge *)
r1 = d;    (* radius of hole *)
L2 = 0.004; (* nail thickness *)
L3 = 0.04; (* nail length *)
L4 = L/8; (* location of nail from bottom *)
Y = 10^3;  (* modulus of elasticity *)
ν = 33/100;  (* Poisson ratio *)

reg = RegionDifference[
   RegionUnion[
    Rectangle[{0, 0}, {L, L}],
    Rectangle[{-L3, L4 - L2/2}, {0, L4 + L2/2}],
    Rectangle[{-L3, (L - L4) - L2/2}, {0, (L - L4) + L2/2}]
    ],
   RegionUnion[
    Disk[{L, 0}, r],
    Disk[{2 d, L - 2 d}, r1]]
   ];
Show[Region[reg], PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This region looks good. Now I try to mesh.

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[reg, "BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> "Continuation", 
   "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.001, "MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0001];
Show[mesh["Wireframe"], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The nails have been lost and the edges are very poorly represented. I have tried different options for `ToElementMesh` but have not hit on one that works. What is happening? Version 11.1 for Windows. Thanks

**Edit**

Helpful user21 gave a solution below which works for the resolution in his example. I have tried to increase the resolution and this is what happens.

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[reg, {{-0.04`, 0.2`}, {0.`, 0.2`}}, 
   "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.001, 
   "BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> {"RegionPlot", "SamplePoints" -> 200} ];
Show[mesh["Wireframe"], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The curved boundaries and the lower part of the vertical straight boundary are badly formed. I would like a high resolution because when doing stress calculations gradients of the solution are needed.   Any more thoughts?

Combining the suggestions from the answers below is successful.

**Further edit**

If you use this mesh you will need to use the workaround from [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/152455/12558). Add the option `"ImproveBoundaryPosition" -> False` to `ToElementMesh`. The mesh coordinates are not all contained within the solution interpolation function. So the final `ToElementMesh` expression was

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[reg, {{-L3, L}, {0, L}}, 
   "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.001, MaxCellMeasure -> 1.1*^-6, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 8, MeshQualityGoal -> 1, 
   "BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> {"RegionPlot", "SamplePoints" -> 200},
   "ImproveBoundaryPosition" -> False];
```

and it worked to give this mesh

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I am a bit skeptical about the `"ImproveBoundaryPosition" -> False` option. The geometry in this question does not show these sharp corners like the one in the linked question. When you plot(?) over the interpolating function do you use the mesh or the region `reg`?

Comment: @user21  The error does not occur when plotting but when the coordinates of the grid are put into the solution interpolation function to get the values. Shall I make a new question?

Comment: Yes, please if you do not mind. Let's see what's going on. As a side note, I may not be able to look at it right way though but I will.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've had success using `AccuracyGoal -> 8` for meshing regions with small dimensions. (Note: Use fractions for greater accuracy)

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
L = 2/10;  (*Bracket side length*)
d = 2/100; (*End edge lenght*)
r = L - d; (*radius of curved edge*)
r1 = d;    (*radius of hole*)
L2 = 4/1000; (*nail thickness*)
L3 = 4/100;  (*nail length*)
L4 = L/8;    (*location of nail from bottom*)
Y = 10^3;    (*modulus of elasticity*)
ν = 33/100;  (*Poisson ratio*)

reg = 
 RegionDifference[
  RegionUnion[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {L, L}], 
  Rectangle[{-L3, L4 - L2/2}, {0, L4 + L2/2}], 
  Rectangle[{-L3, (L - L4) - L2/2}, {0, (L - L4) + L2/2}]], 
  RegionUnion[Disk[{L, 0}, r], Disk[{2 d, L - 2 d}, r1]]];
Show[Region[reg], PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True]

mesh = ToElementMesh[reg, {{-4/100, 2/10}, {0, 2/10}}, 
   "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.001, MaxCellMeasure -> 1*^-5, 
    AccuracyGoal -> 7, MeshQualityGoal -> 1,
   "BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> {"RegionPlot", "SamplePoints" -> 50}];
Show[mesh["Wireframe"], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: In what version have you tried this?

Comment: Version 11.1 and 11.2

Comment: In version 11.1 it fails to find the nails. The curved edges are good though.

Comment: With accuracy goal and with `"BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> {"RegionPlot", "SamplePoints" -> 200` as you have just added seems to work.  Can anyone give guidance on what the `AccuracyGoal` number and the `SamplePoints` number actually refer to?

Comment: What OS do you have? I can not reproduce your example.

Comment: Windows 7, 64-bit

Comment: I get it to work too now, it must have been a skew setting. Thanks. (+1)

Answer (score 15):

These should work:

**Method 1**

```
ToElementMesh[reg,{{-0.04`, 0.2`}, {0.`, 0.2`}},
"MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.005, 
  "BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> {"RegionPlot", 
    "SamplePoints" -> 41}]["Wireframe"]
```

[image: mesh]

The problem is that "Coninuation" fails (which needs to be investigated) and the "RegionPlot" one does need the "SamplePoints" (think "PlotPloints"). Hope this helps.

If you need a finer mesh you can use:

```
ToElementMesh[reg, {{-0.04`, 0.2`}, {0.`, 0.2`}}, 
  "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.005, "MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.00001, 
  "BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> {"RegionPlot", 
    "SamplePoints" -> 41}]["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

**Method 2**

Here is a better way to do it:

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[reg, RegionBounds[reg], 
   "BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> {"BoundaryDiscretizeRegion"}, 
   "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.001, "MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0001];
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

All of these methods are documented in [ToBoundaryMesh](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ToBoundaryMesh.html). There you can find more info.

**Method 3**

Here is yet another way to do it, but that will requite version 11.2:

```
 L = 1./5; d = 1./50; r = L - d; r1 = d; L2 = 1./250; L3 = 1./25; L4 = 
 L/8;
reg = RegionDifference[
   RegionUnion[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {L, L}], 
    Rectangle[{-L3, L4 - L2/2}, {0, L4 + L2/2}], 
    Rectangle[{-L3, (L - L4) - L2/2}, {0, (L - L4) + L2/2}]], 
   RegionUnion[Disk[{L, 0}, r], Disk[{2 d, L - 2 d}, r1]]];
```

Now we make boundary discretizations of the components and construct the region from those:

```
bdr = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion /@ reg[[2]];
bmr = Fold[RegionDifference, bdr]
```

[image]

Next, we create a [NumericalRegion](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/NumericalRegion.html) and attach the boundary mesh to it:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
nr = ToNumericalRegion[reg, RegionBounds[reg]];
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[bmr];
SetNumericalRegionElementMesh[nr, bmesh];
```

When we now mesh that numerical region have both the symbolic and the boundary representation available and a good approximation can be generated:

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[nr];
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

To compare the area of the mesh with the area of the symbolic representation we use:

```
narea = Total[mesh["MeshElementMeasure"], 2];
```

and

```
L = 1/5; d = 1/50; r = L - d; r1 = d; L2 = 1/250; L3 = 1/25; L4 = 
 L/8;
reg2 = RegionDifference[
   RegionUnion[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {L, L}], 
    Rectangle[{-L3, L4 - L2/2}, {0, L4 + L2/2}], 
    Rectangle[{-L3, (L - L4) - L2/2}, {0, (L - L4) + L2/2}]], 
   RegionUnion[Disk[{L, 0}, r], Disk[{2 d, L - 2 d}, r1]]];
sarea = Integrate[1, {x, y} \[Element] reg2];
```

The result:

```
narea - sarea
-2.4810104379269227`*^-7
```

I think this is quite good.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It works for large resolutions but fails for small resolutions. I have added an edit to my original question to show the problem with this approach. Any ideas?

Comment: @Hugh, what do you mean with 'small resolutions' ? Do you mean small mesh cell size?

Comment: Yes I mean small mesh cell size.

Comment: I would appreciate if downvoters leave a small message so that I can respond to the issue.

Comment: I thought this was a neat trick ... thank you for sharing

Comment: If you take the boundary size to` "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.001` in your last example it fails. However adding `AccuracyGoal->8` makes it work.

Comment: @Hugh, Glad you got it to work.

Comment: Thanks to both you and @Young. Can you give me more information on good values to use for  `AccuracyGoal` and `SamplePoints`